# I can't get Deferred DeepLink

Tags: android, facebook

Recently I tested 'deferred deeplink' function by using facebook SDK.
But there is one problem.

**# I did it.**

First, I have completed all of setting for apps by using the "App Ads Helper" function from developers.facebook.com.

## https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amlib.png]

Second, so I obtained the good result by using "DeepLink Test" provided by"App Ads Helper".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGhFG.png]

And I could see what i want (AppLinkData)

06-04 12:58:25.598  11903-11925/? I/DEBUG_FACEBOOK_SDK﹕ Bundle[{**com.facebook.platform.APPLINK_NATIVE_CLASS=, target_url=myapp://myapp.co.kr?test=1111, com.facebook.platform.APPLINK_NATIVE_URL=myapp://myapp.co.kr?test=1111**}]

Third, here is the code what I used.

```
protected void onCreate(){
    .... 
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(getApplicationContext(), 
        BSTracker.getInstance().getFacebookIdMeta() , 
        new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
            if (appLinkData != null) {
                Bundle bundle = appLinkData.getArgumentBundle();
                Log.i("DEBUG_FACEBOOK_SDK", bundle.toString()); 
            } else { 
                Log.i("DEBUG_FACEBOOK_SDK", "AppLinkData is Null"); 
            }
         }
    });
}
```

Finally. This is My App Setting

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHIr2.png]

**Ad Setting**

It is My Ad setting.
i did input the DeepLink in "Get install of your App" Ad Product.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTmx1.png]

**# Problem**

When I created commercial ad at Facebook and released for the audience but I can't get Deferred DeepLink.

Please let me know, anything is wrong with it.

Comment: Can you add some details about how you're determining that you're not getting the deferred deep link?

Comment: Thank you for your favor. but i have a problem what i can't attach some image in my posting because i didn't have 10 reputation. could you tell me your email address?  i hope to explain in email about my app setting , my ad configuration.

Comment: If you want to add a photo, just upload to imgur.com and post a link. If you need to put in personal information, and you believe it to be a bug, then you should report it at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thank you very much. My posting updated. ^^

Comment: How is your ad set up?

Comment: My posting updated. ^^. 
i just created Ad for Install at Facebook without advertising agency. 
should i create Ad through advertising agency?

Comment: This should be fine. You will only get a deferred deep link if you actually click on the ad, which I'm assuming you're doing?

Comment: No. 
i am not affiliated at advertising agency. 
i am a individual. 
should i become MMP( Facebook Provide Mobile measurement marketing partner program ) to get a Deferred Deep Link Data? And i am using Facebook SDK. Not Mobile measurement marketing partner SDK.

Comment: No, you don't need to be an mmp (I'm not sure where you got that idea from), but you do need to click on an ad to get deferred linking information.

Comment: Were you able to make deferred deeplinks work?